# code always shows email error. Email validation error in react native

Tags: react-native, email-validation

I am validating the email in my react native form but there is something wrong in the code and I am not able to find one. Kindly help.

```
class index extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      emailError: "",
  
    };


 emailValidator = (text) => {
    let reg = /^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/;
    if (reg.test(text) === false) {
      this.setState({ emailError: "Please enter a valid email address" });
      return false;
    } else {
      this.setState({ email: text });
    }
  };
render() {
return(

<Input
      keyboardType={"email-address"}
      onBlur={(text) => this.emailValidator(text)}
      placeholder="Email"
        ></Input>
        <Text style={{ color: "red", paddingLeft: 10 }}>
          {this.state.emailError}
        </Text>
)}
```

Even if I type a correct email, it shows the emailError message "Please enter a valid email address " Also on Submit I need to show a modal box saying "Thank you for submission." Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

when email is in expected format, you were just updating `email` in state. so `emailError` does still persist from last email.

Simple fix is to updating  `emailError` back to empty string while in correct email case.

Answer (score 0):

in your emailValidator function when your email is valid, you are not updating emailError.please check below emailValidator function

```
 emailValidator = (text) => {
    let reg = /^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/;
    if (reg.test(text) === false) {
      this.setState({ emailError: "Please enter a valid email address" });
      return false;
    } else {
      this.setState({ email: text, emailError:"" });
    }
  };
```

Comment: please share with me the complete code.?
provide me repo URL